# How to set the clojurescript *print-fn* fn in nodejs

Tags: node.js, clojurescript

I am playing around with compiling clojurescript to nodejs and I just really want to use the `println` function:

```
(println "hello world")
```

However, it gives me an error

```
 No *print-fn* fn set for evaluation environment
```

I've looked around the net but it wasn't clear what was supposed to be done. I really just want to set `*print-fn*` to `js/console.log` but I'm not sure how to do that

Comment: println works fine is cljs+node. Maybe post more info on setup. Do you compile cljs->js? How do you run it?

Comment: I tried https://github.com/martintrojer/cljs-nodejs-coreasync-bootstrap and it has some println which works fine.

Comment: Hi zcaudate, I've updated my answer to integrate with @edbond comments, so it covers both environments: browser and nodejs

Comment: @tangrammer thanks for that. I'm doing some experimentation at the moment.. will update once I've finished messing around.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since [this commit](https://github.com/clojure/clojurescript/commit/da2fa520ae5cd55ade7e263ec3b9a2149eb12f82) the canonical way of redirecting println to the console seems to be:

```
(enable-console-print!)
```

Answer (score 3):

If you can't use `println` in clojurescript browser environment, why don't you (re)define this function inside your code?. I mean something like:

```
(def println[ & more]
  (.log js/console more))
```

on the beginning of your application code

**EDIT:** as @edbond says, in clojurescript/node environment you can use println without more configuration. You can find an example on the clojurescript documentation https://github.com/clojure/clojurescript/wiki/Quick-Start#running-clojurescript-on-nodejs

```
(ns nodehello)

(defn -main [& args]
  (println (apply str (map [\ "world" "hello"] [2 0 1]))))

(set! *main-cli-fn* -main)
```

Comment: I would advise agains using (.log js/console), it will fail in your IE/Edge in production.